# Как получить ID группы в вк апи

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

При попытке извлечь из сообщения ID группы методом:

```
int(event.object.object.message_data.from_id)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_id'
```

Хотя ID пользователя спокойно получает и не какой ошибки нет.

Answer (score 0):

ID группы обычно указан в формате "-190892131" с минусом.

Когда сообщество отправляет сообщение - мы получаем следующий json -

```
"type": "message_new",
"object": {
    "date": 1604068793,
    "from_id": -170475233,
    "id": 0,
    "out": 0,
    "peer_id": 2000000060,
    "text": "Я не знаю такой команды(\nУзнать все команды бота - !help",
    "conversation_message_id": 152,
    "fwd_messages": [],
    "important": false,
    "random_id": 0,
    "attachments": [],
    "is_hidden": false
},
```

При этом никакой проблемы с извлечением не должно возникать ,потому-что иначе никак нельзя извлечь.
В питоне я слабо шарю, но в большинстве случаев везде одинаково идет извлечение данных.

У тебя выдает ошибку о том,что не найден само поле "from_id",чекни в настройках беседы запросы и посмотри,пишет ли у тебя "from_id". Попробуй поставить версию API не ниже 5.80 и будет тебе счастье)